# A colorbar with css3 and jquery or d3js

Tags: jquery, html, css, d3.js, colorbar

Good evening,

my idea is to create a css colorbar such as this concept drawn by me with inkscape:

[image: colorbar mockup]

- Clicking on any gradient point, (let's say between blue and white), should make another step to appear, with the interpolated colors.
- Dragging the rectangle on left or right should move the step position
- Clicking on the rectangle should allow to change the color.

My idea is to implement the various gradient  with `<li>` elements, the pickers with the new html5 `<input type="color">`, and the arrows with some unicode `▲` character or something, it is not crucial for now.

I prepared this jfiddle with a vertical version: http://jsfiddle.net/gyaA4/
and this is the code;

*css*

```
    li{position:relative; display:block; height:150px;
       border:1px solid gray; width:60px; resize:vertical; overflow:auto;}
    input{position:absolute; }
    input:first-child{top:0;}
    input:last-child{bottom:0;}
```

*html*

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="color" value="#38b3b3">
        <input type="color" value="#dddddd">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="color" value="#dddddd">
        <input type="color" value="#38b31e">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="color" value="#38b31e">
        <input type="color" value="#dddddd">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

*jquery*

```
    // Function to set the gradient
    $.fn.grad=function(){
        this.is(":last-child") ? n="end" : n="start";
        l=this.parent();
        v=this.val();
        l.attr("data-"+n,v); // only for the tag
        l.data(n,v); // displaied data
        l.css("background-image","linear-gradient(to bottom,"    
              +l.data("start")+","+l.data("end")+")")
    }

    // Setting the gradient at start and on change,
    $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).grad();
    }).on("change",function(){
        $(this).grad();
    });

    // Splitting the li on click (on ul to extend events to cloned objects)
    $("ul").on("click","li",function(){
        t=$(this)
        h=t.css("height");
        $(this).css("height","calc("+h+" / 2)").clone().insertAfter($(this));
    }).find("input").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

The **bugs** up to now are the following:

- After a click which divides a `<li>` in two halves, it is not possible to use the color picker on the cloned object: the click event is being propagated on the cloned `input` tags.
- After the click the colors are not updated. Well, i will try to take inspiration from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aYD3T/
- Resizing a `<li>` does not automatically affect the width of the next sibling
- The total width is not mantained.
- css does not refletcs the mockup :)

Can you help me to resolve at least a part of these issues? of course, if you think there's a more elegant to do it, I'll appreciate very much.

**EDIT**:

I am also exploring this d3.js solution http://jsfiddle.net/fjW5B/1/

*css*

```
  input{width:700px;}
  li{display:inline-block; width:100px; height:30px; 
     border:1px solid gray; margin:1px; }
```

*html*

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>       
<input 
value="[{&quot;v&quot;:0,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;#000&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:100,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;#ccc&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:120,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;#12d&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:300,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;#1dd&quot;}, {&quot;v&quot;:330,&quot;c&quot;:&quot;#fff&quot;} ]">
  <nav>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

*d3js*

```
update()
d3.select("input").on("change",update)

function update(){
    var data = JSON.parse(d3.select("input").property("value"));
    var li=d3.select("ul").selectAll("li").data(data);
    console.log(data)

    li.enter().append("li")

    li.style("width",function(d,i){
            start=data[i].v;
            i+1 == data.length ? end=d.v : end=data[i+1].v;
        return end-start + "px"
    })
        .style("background-image",function(d,i){
            start=d.c;
            i+1 == data.length ? end='#ffffff' : end=data[i+1].c;
            return "linear-gradient(to right, "+start+","+end+")"});
}
```

Comment: you may jquery slider....

Comment: Look at this site:[jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker) this will hepls you

Comment: You're not actually using D3, are you?

Comment: D3 is another solution that I am considering instead of jQuery, being the fact that it has builtin functions to map arrays into colors.